# Creating a new App Registration in Azure, app disappears

Tags: azure, entra-id

For a specific Azure tenant, when I create a new app registration, it just disappears and is nowhere to be found.

It gets assigned an application id:

[image]

I am also able to create a key for it:

[image]

and view properties for it:

[image]

But when I go to refresh the list of apps (or go somewhere else to pick it for identity access control) - it is just nowhere to be found. Like this:

[image]

If I go to Azure Active Directory Overview, it says I have 4 applications (which fits the number of times I have create a new app registration) - but if I click it - nothing found.

[image]

Note:

- The account I am using a global admin
- This works in all other tenants
- I have also tried doing this using the account that owns the tenant, same issue
- I have tried logging out and back in
- I have waited (days), does not change anything

### What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that you filtered `My apps` in App registrations.

**Solution:**

Choose `All apps` in the columms like this:

[image]

[image]

**Addtional:**

If you want the app to shows in `My apps`, you need to set the owner of this app.

Go to Azure Portal > Azure Acitve Directory > Application registrations > Your App > Settings > Onwers > Add owner > Add your Account > Select

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: ...Facepalm... I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much. :)